# Calculate total between two columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, calculated-columns

I have table named #table and three columns. SinGroup(it does not matter, can be anything), Column1, and Column2.

```
    CREATE TABLE #table(
     sinGroup  NVARCHAR(10)
     ,column1 INT
     ,column2 int 
     );
```

And i have some data:

```
    INSERT INTO #table(sinGroup,column1,column2) VALUES
      ('y1',100,0),
      ('y2',0,60),
      ('y3',40,20),
      ('z1',150,0),
      ('z2',0,50),
      ('z3',0,50)
```

I want to know how to get this result set (c1 - c2 and group by Y and Z and the result shown under the column 1):

```
       SinGroup    C1       C2

         y1        100      0
         y2          0     60
         y3         40     20

          Y         60      0

         z1        150      0
         z2          0     50
         z3          0     50

          Z         50      0
```

And also result like this (c1-c2 and grop by each row,the result show under the column 1)

```
       SinGroup     C1      C2
          y1       100      0
          y1       100      0

          y2         0     60
          y2       -60      0

          y3        40     20
          y3        20      0

          z1       150      0
          z1       150      0

          z2         0     50
          z2       -50      0

          z3         0     50
          z3        -50     0
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/65ff5)

EDIT: 
I have tried something like this but i don't want 4 column, result must be below c1.

```
       select sinGroup, column1, column2, sum(column1) - sum(column2) as c
       from #table
       group by sinGroup,column1,column2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible,  please format those data at the frond-end level. SQL is not a language designed for this kind of tasks.

**Query 1**   [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5e73c/5)

```
WITH summary AS (
  SELECT LEFT(sinGroup,1) AS sinGroup, SUM(C1) - SUM(c2) AS total 
  FROM t1
  GROUP BY LEFT(sinGroup,1)
)
SELECT sinGroup,c1,c2
FROM 
(  SELECT sinGroup,c1,c2, 0 as display_order
  FROM t1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT sinGroup
    ,CASE WHEN total > 0 THEN total ELSE 0 END AS C1
    ,CASE WHEN total < 0 THEN total ELSE 0 END AS C2
    ,1 AS display_order
  FROM summary
 ) t
 ORDER BY LEFT(sinGroup,1),display_order,sinGroup
```

**Query 2**  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5e73c/7)

```
SELECT sinGroup,c1,c2
FROM 
(  SELECT sinGroup,c1,c2, 0 as display_order
  FROM t1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT sinGroup, SUM(C1) - SUM(C2) AS c1, 0 AS C2, 1  as display_order
  FROM t1
  GROUP BY sinGroup
 ) t
 ORDER BY sinGroup,display_order
```

Comment: Can you explain to me the logic of the first query . What role does the column display_Order ( 0 and 1) does not quite understand

Comment: @sqlProfile87, ORDER BY display_Order  is to make sure group result Y, Z are shown under y1, y2, etc..